# how to read a pdf file inside an application?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I am working on an application in which i have to read downloaded pdf file inside my application without using any external application.

By googling i found that there is one library named [iText](http://itextpdf.com/index.php) which is open Source but the problem is i don't know how to use this library inside my application to read the pdf. So can you please provide me any sample code by which i can understand how to use this library..

Thanks to all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add the pdf library.

There is already a library and some more.

https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

You should read the readme there is everything explained you need.

Hope could helpya
:)

Answer (score 0):

I had used VuDroid it uses NDK and you can find source [here](http://code.google.com/p/vudroid/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/vudroid/pdfdroid/?r=52#pdfdroid%2Fcodec)

There are other libraries as well that you can use ...just google it. But it worked for me successfully.

Comment: but i have problem with building ndk please let me know how can i build my project using ndk....